# Drupal hook_theme error

Tags: drupal-7, hook-theme

I am attempting to apply a custom theme to a single page. The page is one I have setup using hook_menu.
I have impletemted hook_theme but when I refresh the website, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /srv/bindings/baf029321aa248e5907866cc7de3a6d6/code/includes/form.inc on line 1044

The following is my code:

```
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items['mymodule'] = array(
        'title' => 'My-module',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('mymodule_admin_page'),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_admin_page(){
    drupal_set_message('My-module admin page responding');

    return theme('mymodule_template');
}

function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    drupal_set_message('My-module theme hook responding');

    return array(
        'mymodule_template' => array(
            #'render element' => 'elements', 
            'template' => 'mytemplate',
            'path'  =>  drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates',
        )
    ); 
}
```

As far as I can tell, the error occurs when I add the forward slash to `'path'  => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates',`.
If I remove the slash the error goes away but then, the system tries and fails to find mytemplate.tpl.php because it's looking at `mymodule/templatemytemplate.tpl.php`.

Comment: move `drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates'` to another variable then use it in `'path' => $myVariable`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
this menu alwaya call a form function not call a theme function

```
$items['mymodule'] = array(
        'title' => 'My-module',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',//this is use a get the form
        'page arguments' => array('contactform_form'),// this is use a name of form 
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
 );

function contactform_form($form, &$form_state)
{
     //write a form attributes
}
```